# Is it possible for me to tame a creeper on minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was watching a video on YouTube where this one guy tamed a creeper. Is it possible to tame a creeper on the PE and if so how?

Comment: you can't tame a creeper without mods. you can lead it around but nothing more

Comment: That guy actually abused bugs in the game, the creeper wasn't actually tamed, just failed to notice the player is within explosion range.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot tame hostile mobs with an unmodded version of minecraft regardless of what platform your play it on.

Comment: Oh. Darn. Might be harder getting one than I thought