# Can you tame a creeper?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have seen videos that state you can tame creepers, but I don't know how.

How can I tame a creeper?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119721/is-it-possible-for-me-to-tame-a-creeper-on-minecraft-pe

Answer (score 6):

**Not in Vanilla**.

You can do it with a mod though:

[Tamed Mobs Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2274263-tamed-mobs-mod-1-2-updated-added-level-system-guis)

[[1.7.2] [1.6.4] [Forge] Tameable (pet) Creepers](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1293117-1-7-2-1-6-4-forge-tameable-pet-creepers)

Comment: so can you or not cause i need to know i know how to tame ocelet

Comment: If you install the mods I linked to, or any other relevant mod, then you will be able. If you don't have them installed, and you DONT install these mods you wont and you cant tame a creeper.

Comment: ok i wont no mods you say right

Comment: dude i have a nother question

Comment: i tried but they dont work

Comment: @dwight If you have a new question, ask it by clicking Ask Question at the top of the page and making a new question post.